# Pin connection on beam - FEA analysis

Tags: finite-element-method, beam

I am establishing a MatLab FEA code for determining the stiffness of a structure. Diagram of the structure is added below.
I have established a code for determining the stiffness of the structure, but I am unsure of how to treat node B. Element AC is one continuous beam with element BD connected to it through a pin connection. That is, element BD will only experience axial forces (= no angular displace), while element AC at node B will experience axial forces AND bending moment, causing angular displacement.
So how do I treat this node? I can not say angular displacement is 0, because it is not for element AC. But if I say it is different from zero, the connection will act as if it was welded together.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Regards

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! Are you using the direct stiffness method for your analysis?

Comment: If you by, the direct stiffness method, mean hand calculations, then no. I establish a 6x6 matrix for every element with given values. Afterwards I rotate them into the global system and make then correspond with the global DOFs. Then at last sum up the element stiffness matrices. Thanks.

Comment: That's the definition of the [direct stiffness method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_stiffness_method). I'll try to find time to answer this tomorrow.